# How to split a string (containing no spaces) with multiple delimiters in Python?

Tags: python, delimiter

I have a string looking like this:

`obj = "<dnvirnfgvireg>hellothere<akdnefbuebuf>"`

and I want to split it, getting only "hellothere". The "hellothere" is not the same every time and due to this I cannot specify how it looks like.

Comment: If the <dnvirnfgvireg> is everytime the same, you should remove the n number of characters (str[n:]) because one day, the string "<dnvirnfgvireg>" will be in your "hellothere" string an it will cause a problem. You can do the same thing for the second <>

Comment: This question is different from the marked duplicate.

Comment: How do I remove them? By using replace? I tried this like: `line.replace(line[:25], '')`, but when I print the line nothing is replaced.